# Cyberprograms vs Autosofts

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Do Rigger Cyberprograms, like Signal Scrub, count against the Device Rating of the RCC? If I use a program, I can use one less autosoft?

Comment: It would be really, really helpful if people who gave -1 votes commented to explain why :o/

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting that either. I +1ed this because it sounds an awful lot like a techie question someone here could come up with a definitive answer for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am reading, cyber-programs made for an RCC seem to take up the same slot as an autosoft.  That means that getting a Signal Scrubber program can make the RCC more efficient, since you can get a Noise Reduction of 2 with only one point from your device rating.  Though, it seems that RCC programs might be an inefficient use of device rating, for the most part, unless you have high-rating drones.  I would load them up and use them off of runs, then only load up Signal Scrubber for two points of Noise Reduction.

Comment: In this case VM is worse than nothing. It gives you 2 slots on the RCC for the cost of one. No net gain here, but it costs money, and increases feedback damage.

Comment: I would disagree.  A rigger is not always jumped into drones.  They can run in captain's chair just fine and be amazing.  And your RCC is still taking the damage first before you do, unless you're jumped in.  One more damage to your RCC is fine, in my opinion, if you don't plan on engaging a target.  VM for long-range scouting is a great idea.  If you have concerns, use the extra slot for Encryption for a +1 Firewall.  That will help mitigate getting attacked in the Matrix.